# Programming with Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm learning Erlang and I'm trying to understand this code that was used as an example.

```
-module(tutorial5).
-export([format_temps/1]).

format_temps(List_of_cities) ->
    convert_list_to_c(List_of_cities). 

convert_list_to_c([{Name, {f, F}} | Rest]) ->
    Converted_City = {Name, {c, (F -32)* 5 / 9}},
    [Converted_City | convert_list_to_c(Rest)];

convert_list_to_c([City | Rest]) ->
    [City | convert_list_to_c(Rest)];

convert_list_to_c([]) ->
    [].
```

I am unsure of how to use these methods to get what I need. The most I know about this is that I'm supposed to be able to form a list of cities and their temperatures, and then be able to convert their temperatures from farenheit to celsius and vice versa. Any HELP would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

The only callable function in the module `tutorial5` is `format_temps/1` (it takes one argument). It takes a list of city/temp where each city/temp is a *tuple* of the form `{City,{f,Fahrenheit}}` for example `{berlin,{f,60}}`. The function return a list of city/temp where the temp part is now `{c,Celsius}`. An example call from the shell with its return would be:

```
> tutorial5:format_temps([{berlin,{f,59}},{london,{f,50}},{stockholm,{f,50}}]).
[{berlin,{c,15.0}},{london,{c,10.0}},{stockholm,{c,10.0}}]
```

Some points to note are:

- When calling a function in another module you **MUST** always include the module name
- The words starting with lower case letters are *atoms*, literal constants with a name, while those starting with upper case letters (from my text) are *variables*. The look alike but are very different.